# Javascript split array and call it over and over again

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have this test function for right not that I'm trying to split the array at a value, and then reset that value to a different point.

```
if (test_flag = true) {
    peak = 9;
    arr = [6,2,6,8,3,2,6,8,9,2,26,8,2,1,6,9,3,4,7,9,8,1,9,2];
}
arr = arr.slice(peak);
peaks = find_the_peaks(arr);
test_flag == false;
peak = peaks;
```

So what's supposed to happen is, the flag is defaulted to true, so peak is set to 9 and arr is set to that array. We slice the array at the current peak (9 in this case) and then call 'find_the_peaks' which is my working peak search function and that returns 10. Now from there, peak should be reset to 10, and the array should be sliced from there, leaving

arr = [2,26,8,2,1,6,9,3,4,7,9,8,1,9,2];

but for some reason it doesn't do that. I'm not sure what I'm missing here but I haven't been able to find it.

I need to pass in a new array each time and slice at the new peak position until there are no more peaks left in the array. Each time the button is pressed, the current array is sliced at the current peak, that new array is then passed and a new peak is found.

Comment: Does `find_the_peaks` return an array?

Comment: `.slice()` takes *the index*, not the value. When you do `arr.slice(peak);` that will slice *from the 10th element* (index 9) to the end. The tenth element is the `2` immediately after the `9`.

Comment: Also `if (test_flag = true)` is assignment, not an equality check.

Comment: With that said, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. You've explained some steps in some algorithm but it doesn't seem to match the code. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @VLAZ so when find_the_peaks returns 10, that value should still be passed in and slice the new array at position 10 and then return for there etc. but it doesn't. Is there another built in function like slice that would work better?

Comment: You could consider changing `find_the_peaks` to return an index instead, it would be more to the point

Comment: I changed it so now it does return the index. I have it slicing at the index, it does it once still but not repeatable. Same code as above for slice functions, just changed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using slice to split the array, but then adding back on the peak point that I found as well. So my function looked like

```
if (right_split_flag == true) {
    array_to_be_analyzed_right = float_array;
    peak = peak_main;
}

array_to_be_analyzed_right = array_to_be_analyzed_right.slice(peak);
peak = find_the_peaks(array_to_be_analyzed_right);

frequency_of_peak = center_frequency + offset_val[peak + 1];
peak_value_right[0] = freq;
peak_value_right[1] = array_to_be_analyzed_right[peak];
peak_value_right[2] = peak + peak_index_pos;
right_peak_flag = false;
right_split_flag = false;
return peak_value_right;
```

peak_value_right is my tuple I'm displaying to the screen with the frequency, peak point, and then the position plus the peak points position. Doing this splitting left, all I did was change the length of the array to be 1-length of the peak position. My code looked like

```
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == function_peak_val) {
            arr.length = i - 1;
        }
    }
    return arr;
```

where function_peak_val is my peak position and arr is my array that's being passed in